# Excel Array from cell range

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Hi Guys I'm trying to tweak a formula. I need to change the hardcoded array to reference a cell range.

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(B1:B196,{"*yes*","*no*"},C1:C196,"agree"))
```

However I would like it to look like:

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(B1:B196,A1;A2,C1:C196,"agree"))
```

The wild cards are important as I need to do a countif or within stings of text.

Wouldn't mind a VBA soulution.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: have you tried `INDIRECT()` ?

Comment: @MacroMan no I havn't yet, how would I incorporate this?

Comment: I was going to explain, but the answer below using concatenation is much better tbh.

Comment: You have a good answer below but in the interest of tweaking the formula, are the wildcards *really* necessary? Even if they are, a `*no*` or even a `*yes*` can produce a lot of false positives.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enter this as an array formula with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>enter</kbd>:

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(B1:B196,"*" & A1:A2 & "*",C1:C196,"agree"))
```

Comment: Although it should be noted that using SUMPRODUCT rather than SUM would also suffice, and would not require array-entry.

Comment: Thanks doug and @xor I decided to use sumproduct just for convenience. But used your formula doug cheers guys really appreciate it